# regex command line with single-line flag

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I would need to use regex in a `bash` script to substitute text in a file that might be on multiple lines.
I would pass `s` as flag in other regex engines that I know but I have a hard time for bash.

`sed` as far as I know doesn't support this feature.
`perl` it obviously does but I can not make it work in a one liner
`perl -i -pe 's/<match.+match>//s $file`

example text:

```
DONT_MATCH

<match some text here
    and here
match>

DONT_MATCH
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: What have you tried so far with `sed`? If you have GNU `sed`, something like `sed '/<match/,/match>/c\replace text with this text' file.txt` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -z 's/<match.*match>//g' file
DONT_MATCH



DONT_MATCH
```

With any sed:

```
$ sed  'H;1h;$!d;x; s/<match.*match>//g' file
DONT_MATCH



DONT_MATCH
```

Both the above approaches read the whole file into memory.  If you have a big file (e.g. gigabytes), you might want a different approach.

#### Details

With GNU sed, the `-z` option reads in files with NUL as the record separator.  For text files, which never contain NUL, this has the effect of reading the whole file in.

For ordinary sed, the whole file can be read in with the following steps:

- `H` - Append current line to hold space
- `1h`  - If this is the first line, overwrite the hold space
  with it
- `$!d` - If this is not the last line, delete pattern space
  and jump to the next line.
- `x`  - Exchange hold and pattern space to put whole file in
  pattern space

Comment: While all of the answer work, I choose this one because sed is a tool already used in the same script and is the easiest code to read.

Answer (score 4):

By default, `.` doesn't match a line feed. `s` simply makes `.` matches any character.

You are reading the file a line at a time, so you can't possibly match something that spans multiple lines. Use `-0777` to treat the entire input as a one line.

```sh
perl -i -0777pe's/<match.+match>//s' "$file"
```

Comment: I thought that s (single line mode) was doing exactly that. Treat the input string as a single line, therefore matching also line breaks.

Comment: It does treat the entire input as a single line (by making `.` not treat LF specially), but it still can't possibly match against stuff you haven't read yet! `$_`, against which you were matching, never contained both `<match some text here` and `match>` at the same time

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^<match/{:a;/match>$/!{N;ba};s/.*//}' file
```

Gather up a collection of lines from one beginning `<match` to one ending `match>` and replace them by nothing.

N.B. This will act on all such collections throughout the file and the end-of-file condition will not effect the outcome. To only act on the first, use:

```
sed '/^<match/{:a;/match>$/!{N;ba};s/.*//;:b;n;bb}' file
```

To only act on the second such collection use:

```
sed -E '/^<match/{:a;/match>$/!{N;ba};x;s/^/x/;/^(x{2})$/{x;s/.*//;x};x}' file
```

The regex `/^(x{2})$/` can be tailored to do more intricate matching e.g. `/^(x|x{3,6})$/` would match the first and third to sixth collections.